# How do i pass JSON data from viewController to UIView to be used for a label

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently trying to find a way to pass the JSON i receive from my API request to my UIView so it can be used for label text however i don't use storyboards and all my viewcontroller's are made programatically so below is the file i'm trying to get the data to and the function i'm receiving the data which is in my viewcontroller

profileView.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import PureLayout

class profileView: UIView {
var shouldSetupConstraints = true



var profileImageContainer = UIView()
var profileImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
var first_name = UILabel()
var last_name = UILabel()


let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
let textFieldAppearance = UITextField.appearance()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: (0/255.0), green: (114/255.0), blue: (255/255.0), alpha: 1).cgColor , UIColor(red: (0/255.0), green: (198/255.0), blue: (255/255.0), alpha: 1).cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradient.cornerRadius = 4

    profileImage.center = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width/2, y:screenSize.height/2)


    self.addSubview(profileImage)

   first_name.frame = CGRect(x: screenSize.height/11, y: screenSize.width/2, width: 100, height: 50)
   first_name.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-light", size: 24)
    first_name.textColor = .black

    self.addSubview(first_name)



    textFieldAppearance.keyboardAppearance = .light


}






required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


override func updateConstraints() {
    if(shouldSetupConstraints) {
        // AutoLayout constraints
        shouldSetupConstraints = false
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
}


}
```

mainViewController.swift

```
@objc func login(_ sender: UIButton){
    let url = URL(string: "http://myapi.com/login.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //getting values from text fields
    let email = loginViewer.email.text
    let password = loginViewer.password.text

    //creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
    let postParameters = "email="+email!+"&password="+password!;

    //adding the parameters to request body
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        //parsing the response
        do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

            //parsing the json
            if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                //creating a string
                var msg : String!
                var first_name : String!
                var last_name : String!
                //getting the json response
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                first_name = parseJSON["first_name"] as! String?
                last_name = parseJSON["last_name"] as! String?
                //printing the response
                print(msg)
                print(first_name)
                print(last_name)

                let profileView = profile()
                profileView.first_name = first_name
                self.present(profile(), animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    //executing the task
    task.resume()

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
let profileView = profile()
profileView.first_name = first_name
self.present(profile(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

first you can't present a view , only a VC , so you need to embed this view inside a VC , **OR**

```
var profileV:profileView!
```

//

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.profileV = profileView(frame:self.view.frame)
   self.profileV.first_name.text = first_name
   self.view.addSubview(profileV)
}
```

To remove

```
self.profileV.removeFromSuperview()
```

the downSide is lack of animation , so insert it inside a VC to take value of **animated:true**

Comment: is this the best way to pass JSON data or is there a better way

Comment: you need to use **Codable** instead of **JSONSerialization** , and make it model oriented , also don't create UIView subclass , directly create the variables inside a programmatically VC and send the model to it

Comment: also a general tip don't force-unwrap a value from a json only if you're 100% sure that you'll receive it